# Why would one autorelease one's own property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Here's a code example to show what I mean:

```
- (void) setup {
  [self setupObjectModel];
  [self setupStoreCoordinator];
}

- (void) setupObjectModel {
  NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Model" withExtension:@"momd"];
  self.managedObjectModel = [[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `managedObjectModel`is a `strong`property or defined with attribute `retain`, the setter will automatically retain the passed argument, thus `autorelease`ing it will prevent a memory leak (if you don't do it, the retain count of the `NSManagedObjectModel` will be 2 although only `managedObjectModel`points to it.)

This is equivalent to

```
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

assuming the setter has the default behaviour

Comment: But why not release instead of autorelease?

Comment: If you `release` instead of `autorelease`, at the end of the `release` call the object will inspect its `retaincount` and see that it is zero, and will call `dealloc` **before** the `managedObjectModelis` setter will have a chance to retain it. Your property will then point to a deallocated object and raise `SEGFAULT` at the first occasion.

Comment: If you still have a question, please ask it and I will try my  best to answer it. Otherwise, mark this answer as accepted please.

Comment: Can you clarify just a bit more? I sort of get what you're saying. If you could show in a code fashion with an example, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: There is not much code to show here, it's only a question as to when the object gets deallocated. If you `autorelease`, you just say "decrease this object's retain count sometime in the near future". Whereas as if you `release` it, what you are saying is "decrease this object's retain count **now**, and if by any chance it is 0 (which will happen in our case) **remove it** from memory". In the lattercase, once the object is deallocated the pointer justs points to a random serie of bytes in memory